# Is there a cross-platform way to build a distribution?

Tags: perl, dependency-management, cpan

I'm writing a CI script to build a Perl library located at GitHub.

Now I do it this way:

```
cpanp i Module::Install # and other configure dependencies  
perl Makefile.PL
make dist
cpanp i Foo-Bar-6.66.tar.gz
```

- I want to create a PAR packages for all the dependencies I build. That's why I use cpanp.
- Unlike `cpanm .`, `cpanp i .` is buggy and uses the name of the directory to name the distribution, which is incorrect. That's why I use this make dist step.

I can use something else as long as my PARs are built, of course. There is https://metacpan.org/pod/PAR::Dist#blib_to_par function which can in principle be called during any other build process.

The problem with my current approach is that:

- the list of configure dependencies is maintained manually. I'd like to use some tool which does it automatically
- on Windows `make` may be called `gmake` or `dmake` depending on perl version. I want to use an existing autodetection logic instead of rolling my own
- Finally, I'd like autodetection of Makefile.PL vs Build.PL so I can copy-paste the code for different distributions

My question is: Is there any way to build local sources of a distribution either by using cpanp (this way would solve my problem) or in any other way which works for different versions of Windows Perl and builds PAR distributions of dependencies?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant for your case, but there is a [perl module Travis-CI helper script](https://github.com/travis-perl/helpers) that will work with any of `Makefile.PL`, `Build.PL`, or `Dist::Zilla`

Comment: @Borodin In case it's not obvious from "the problem" section, I added an explicit question in the end.

Comment: @HåkonHægland The script is specific to both PerlBrew and Travis, so it isn't helpful to the question. However, I can still use some ideas from it elsewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution myself.

1. CPANPLUS comes with another tool besides `cpanp` named `cpan2dist`. `cpan2dist --archive Foo-Bar-6.66.tar.gz` works as intended - it builds distributions of dependencies and the current tarball, and autodetects the necessary build tool the way `cpanp` does.
2. To determine the real `make` you can use `CPANPLUS::Config->new->get_prog('make')`. It again uses the same autodetection logic as `CPANPLUS` so it's pretty robust.